# Angularjs:Need help on two way binding(bipolar binding)

Tags: php, html, angularjs, data-binding

When a value change in the back-end(in my case Mysql,Patient details) With any other user(other console) ,i want to update that values on another page at same time(Without refreshing the page)  .how it is possible. my code is given below.

**myscript.js**

```
var ajaxApp=angular.module('ajaxApp',[]);
ajaxApp.controller('ajaxController',function ajaxController($scope,$http){
$http.get('core/getdata.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.patient=data;
});
});
```

**my php page**

```html
<tr ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="p in    patient|filter:pnametext|limitTo:10">
    <td><div class="btn btn-info">{{p.opNo}}</div></td>
                <td><b><a href="getPtDetails.php?pId={{p.pId}}">{{p.pName | uppercase}}</a></b></td>
                <td>
                <div ng-switch on="p.pCatId">
                  <div ng-switch-when="1">
                    ONE
                  </div>
                  <div ng-switch-when="2">
                   TWO
                  </div>
                  <div ng-switch-when="3">
                    THREE
                  </div>
               
              </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{p.pAge}}</td>
                <td>{{p.pHusFather}}</td>
                <td>{{p.phNumber}}</td>
                <td><a href="patientQ.php?pId={{p.pId}}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Add to Queue</button></a></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You need to run the AJAX call frequently and update the view. Use a timer and call the AJAX function.

Comment: You could implement using common shareable service..so that data will share among each controller through the service.. **OR** you could use event `$broadcast` to intimate other and pass the data in it..listner attached to that event will get called once event has broadcasted

Answer (score 3):

suggest use socket.io(web socket) group people editing the same content in same chanel, broadcast modification to others, and notify other people and apply change. ajax is not real time and costs more
http://socket.io/

```js
socket.connect(xx);
socket.on('change', function(data) {
  alert('change happen!');
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.$apply();
})
$scope.$watch('data', function() {
  if (change) {
    socket.emit('change', $scope.data);
  }
})
```